# c++/cli interface implementation -- ambiguous call to member defined in interface base class and System::Object

Tags: c#, .net, generics, interface, c++-cli

I am trying to implement an interface (defined in C#) in C++/CLI.  When attempting to call one of the methods, I am getting a rather vexing error: "Error C2385   ambiguous access of 'Equals'"  Hints in the log file suggest that Equals could be referring to Object::Equals(Object^, Object^)  but I find that strange for two reasons: 1- Object::Equals is a static method, not a member method and the call (see below) is clearly accessed as a member by the "->" operator.  The second part I find strange is that it mentions Object::Equals twice.  See the hints from the log at the bottom after the interface, implementations and test code are shown.

The interface is defined in C# as:

```
public interface ICompleteComparer<in T> : ICompleteComparer, IEqualityComparer<T>, IComparer<T>
{
    bool IsDefaultCompatible { get; }

}

/// <summary>
/// Not to be implemented directly, implement generic version instead please.
/// </summary>
public interface ICompleteComparer : IEqualityComparer, IComparer
{
    Type ComparedType { get; }
}
```

I am attempting to define an implementation of ICompleteComparer in C++/CLI as a *value class*.

Here is what I have so far:

```
public value class SillierIntegerComparer : ICompleteComparer<int> 
{
public:

    property virtual bool IsDefaultCompatible {bool get() { return true; }}

    property virtual Type^ ComparedType {Type^ get() {return  Int32::typeid; }}


    virtual int Compare(Object^ x, Object^ y) = System::Collections::IComparer::Compare
    {
        if (x == nullptr || y == nullptr)
            throw gcnew ArgumentNullException();

        if (x == y)
            return 0;

        int^ xIntPtr = safe_cast<int^>(x);
        int^ yIntPtr = safe_cast<int^>(y);

        if (xIntPtr == nullptr || yIntPtr == nullptr)
        {
            throw gcnew InvalidCastException();
        }

        return Compare(*xIntPtr, *yIntPtr);
    }

    virtual bool Equals(int x, int y)
    {
        return x == y;
    }

    virtual int GetHashCode(Object^ obj) = System::Collections::IEqualityComparer::GetHashCode
    {
        if (obj == nullptr)
            throw gcnew ArgumentNullException();

        int^ intPtr = safe_cast<int^>(obj);
        if (intPtr == nullptr)
            throw gcnew InvalidCastException();
        return *intPtr;
    }

    virtual int GetHashCode(int obj) = System::Collections::Generic::IEqualityComparer<int>::GetHashCode
    {
        return obj;
    }

    virtual int Compare(int x, int y) = System::Collections::Generic::IComparer<int>::Compare
    {
        if (x == y)
            return 0;
        return x > y ? 1 : -1;
    }

    virtual bool Equals(Object^ other) override
    {
        if (other == nullptr)
            return false;
        SillierIntegerComparer^ otherPtr = safe_cast<SillierIntegerComparer^>(other);
        return otherPtr != nullptr;
    }

private:

    virtual bool TypedInterfaceEquals(int x, int y) sealed = System::Collections::Generic::IEqualityComparer<int>::Equals
    {
        return x == y;
    }

    virtual bool InterfaceEquals(Object^ x, Object^ y) sealed = System::Collections::IEqualityComparer::Equals
    {
            if (x == nullptr || y == nullptr)
            throw gcnew ArgumentNullException();

        if (x == y)
            return true;

        int^ xIntPtr = safe_cast<int^>(x);
        int^ yIntPtr = safe_cast<int^>(y);

        if (xIntPtr == nullptr || yIntPtr == nullptr)
        {
            throw gcnew InvalidCastException();
        }

        return *xIntPtr == *yIntPtr;
    }
};
```

The test code is as follows:

```
    SillierIntegerComparer imSilly;
    ICompleteComparer<int>^ comparer = %imSilly;
    //Console::WriteLine(comparer == nullptr);
    const int value = 6;
    int otherValue = 7;
    //StupidIntegerComparer comparer;
    Console::WriteLine(L"Hello World");
    //bool areEqual = imSilly.Equals(value, value);
    bool isLessThan = comparer->Compare(value, otherValue) < 0;
    ***bool areEqual = comparer->Equals(value, otherValue);***
    int hashA = value.GetHashCode();
    //int hashB = imSilly.GetHashCode(value);
    int hashB = comparer->GetHashCode(value);
    Console::WriteLine(String::Format(L"Standard hash: {0}, Comparer hash: {1}, Are equal: {2}", hashA, hashB, hashA == hashB));
```

The line that produces the error is "bool areEqual = comparer->Equals(value, otherValue);"  The code works if: 
    1) the line is removed (assigning a const value to areEqual)
    2) we use imSilly directly via imSilly.Equals(value, otherValue) rather 
       than through the interface.

The error hints produced by the compiler are as follows:

> Help.cpp(23): error C2385: ambiguous access of 'Equals'
>
> Help.cpp(23): note: could be the 'Equals' in base 'System::Object'
>
> Help.cpp(23): note: or could be the 'Equals' in base
>
> 'System::Collections::IEqualityComparer'
>
> Help.cpp(23): note: or could be the 'Equals' in base 'System::Object'
>
> Help.cpp(23): note: or could be the 'Equals' in base
>
> 'System::Collections::Generic::IEqualityComparer' 3>
>
> Help.cpp(23): note: or could be the 'Equals' in base 'System::Object'

So, how am I supposed to resolve this inheritance pickle?  While I am extremely comfortable with C# and quite comfortable with *native* C++, I must admit to being a total neophyte to C++/CLI and I usually find it vexing enough to want to avoid using it. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Does it work if you remove contravariance in the interface? Or if you remove `const` from `value` ? BTW, `safe_cast` is like a direct cast in C#. If you want the equivalent of `as`, use `dynamic_cast` (if a cast fails, `safe_cast` throws, `dynamic_cast` returns `nullptr`)

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment about the difference between dynamic_cast and safe_cast in the context of C++/CLI.  That has been very helpful.  I was able to resolve the problem (in a somewhat satisfactory way) by adding "new" to the equals method definition in the C# interface.